# CSS doesn't seem to be working in my HTML file. How come?

Tags: html, css

I tried it in both Chrome and Firefox, so there doesn't seem to be a problem with the browser. My CSS is valid, but when I run my HTML through validation it says "Bad value “stylesheet” for attribute rel on element link: The string “stylesheet” is not a registered keyword." which I'm not sure what that means. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel =“stylesheet” href=“javajam.css” type=“text/css”>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>

<nav><b>
<a href = "index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;
<a href = "menu.html">Menu</a>&nbsp;
<a href = "music.html">Music</a>&nbsp;
<a href = "jobs.html">Jobs</a>&nbsp;
</b></nav>

<ul>
<li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
<li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
<li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
<li>Open Mic Night Every Friday</li>
</ul>

<dl>
<dt>54321 Route 42</dt>
<dd></dd>
<dt>Ellison Bay, WI 54210</dt>
<dd></dd>
<dt>888-555-5555</dt>
<dd></dd>
</dl>

<br>

<footer><small><i>
Copyright © 2016 JavaJam Coffee House
</i></small></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
color : #2E0000;
background-color : #F5F5DC;
}

h1 {
background-color : #D2B48C;
}

footer {
color : #000000;
background-color : #D2B48C;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet” href="javajam.css" type="text/css">
```

I replaced some of the weird quotes you had in there.

Comment: You missed the closing one after stylesheet and after. css!

Comment: Good catch! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix the problem. I'm surprised different quotes can make such a difference (new to HTML here). I'm using TextEdit; is there a way for me to change the preferences so it always uses those "normal" quotes? Thanks again

Comment: They make a huge difference, as only regular double quotes are used in any programming language I know of. I don't know TextEdit, but it doesn't sound like a professional code editor to me if it does that kind of stuff. I would recommend using SublimeText for starters.

Comment: There are two places you need to disable them. Open TextEdit -> Preferences, uncheck "Smart quotes" and "Smart dashes" and save. The other place is TextEdit -> Edit -> Substitutions.